# Plotting dots layer using tmap over "World" basemap

Tags: r, geospatial, tmap

I am working on geospatial data :

```
 place_name    id region_country     x     y
    <chr>      <dbl> <chr>          <dbl> <dbl>
     1 Barcelona  10102 Spain           41.4  2.18
     2 Bilbao     10103 Spain           43.2 -2.97
     3 Cadiz      10104 Spain           36.5 -6.30
     4 Gibraltar  10106 Spain           36.1 -5.35
     5 La Coruña  10107 Spain           43.4 -8.38
```

I want to plot this cities over the World basemap of tmap.

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
data("World")
```

Here are my data :

```
x <- c(41.38333, 43.25000, 36.53361, 36.13333, 43.36667)
y <- c(2.18333, -2.96667, -6.29944, -5.35000, -8.38333)
```

Creating a data.frame object :

```
 geocode <- data.frame(x,y)
```

Converting to sf object :

```
geocode2 <- st_as_sf(geocode, coords = c("x", "y"))
```

Building the map :

```
map1 <- tm_shape(World) +  # basemap
        tm_fill() +
        tm_borders() +
        tm_shape(geocode2)+      # dots shape
        tm_dots()

map1
```

The error :

```
Error in if (!tmaptools::is_projected(shp)) { : valeur manquante là où TRUE / FALSE est requis
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is specify a CRS ([Coordinate Reference System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_reference_system)) when applying the `sf::st_as_sf()` function. It gives the frame of reference for what would otherwise be just some numbers.

Your data has the look of GPS coordinates, which are in WGS84 = EPSG:4326.

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
data("World")

x <- c(41.38333, 43.25000, 36.53361, 36.13333, 43.36667)
y <- c(2.18333, -2.96667, -6.29944, -5.35000, -8.38333)

geocode <- data.frame(x,y)

geocode2 <- st_as_sf(geocode, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)

map1 <- tm_shape(World) +  # basemap
  tm_borders() +
  tm_shape(geocode2) +      # dots shape
  tm_dots(col = "red", size = .3)

map1
```

[image]

Note that you may want to swap the X and Y coordinates in your `st_as_sf` call to have your points placed on the Iberian peninsula and not Equatorial Africa :)